# Bellman Equation definition

Tags: dynamic-programming, reinforcement-learning, definition

I am trying to understand Bellman Equation and facing with some confusing moments.
1) In different sources I met different definitions of Bellman Equation.
Sometimes it is defined as value-state function

> v(s) = R + y*V(s')

Sometimes it is defined as action-state function

> q(s, a) = r + max(q(s', a'))

Are both of these definitions correct? How Bellman equation was introduced in the original paper?

Answer (score 1):

Bellman equation gives a definite form to dynamic programming solutions and using that we can generalise the solutions to optimisations problems which are recursive in nature and follow the **optimal substructure** property.

Optimal substructure in simpler terms means that the given problem can be broken down into smaller sub problems which require the same solution with smaller data. If an optimal solution to the smaller problem can be computed then it means the given problem (larger one) can also be computed.

Let's denote the problem solution for given state `S` by value `V(S)`, `S` is the state or the subproblem. Let's denote the cost that would incur by choosing action `a(i)` at state `S` be `R`. `R` will be a function `f(S, a(i))`, where `a` is the set of all possible actions that can be performed on state `S`.

`V(S) = max{ f(S, a(i)) + y * V(S') }`   where `max` is taken by iterating over all possible `i`.  `y` is a fixed constant that taxes the subproblem to bigger problem transition, for most problems `y = 1`, so you can ignore it for now.

So basically at any given sub-problem `S`, `V(S)` will give us the most optimal solution by choosing all combinations of actions `a(i)` that can be performed and the next state that will be created with that action. If you think recursively and are habitual to such stuff then it's easy to see why the above equation is correct.

I would suggest to solve dynamic programming problems and look at some standard problems and their solutions to get an idea how those problems are broken down into smaller similar problems and solved recursively. After that, the above equation will make more sense. Also, you will realise that two equations you have written above are almost the same thing, just they are written in a bit different manner.

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/top-20-dynamic-programming-interview-questions/) is a list of more commonly known DP problems and their solutions.